# Modal verbs of probability

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

'I think the doctors didn't expect Bob to wake up.'
I must change this sentence using May. Which version is correct? 
'The doctors may have not been expecting Bob to wake up.'
'The doctors may have not expected Bob to wake up.'

Comment: Which to pick is personal preference, but I don’t think either fully reflects the original.

Comment: More idiomatic is _The doctors may not have expected Bob to wake up_. This could be ambiguous as to whether they had no expectation either way, or expected him not to wake up; but in practice it usually means the latter.